# How do I update node in laravel forge?

Tags: node.js, laravel-forge

I am trying to update node to version 18 from version 14 as my old version is no longer supported. I have tried running `npm install -g node` but it fails to execute. I can't install n either to make the update as it also fails to execute. What commands should I run in laravel-forge to update node?

Comment: I’m not sure if your problem is specific to Larvel Forge, but you often want to manage your node version with a… version manager (such as nvm, nvs, n, etc). Or you can just install the latest version of node via its installer (or a package manager). In addition to that, you can install a local copy of node for your project by installing it as a dependency (`npm i node`). When having node installed as a package, you should either run it through npm scripts or execute the node binary from the `node_modules` directory

Comment: @fardjad I did try and install n, unfortunately it fails install. ```npm i node``` worked! thanks so much. Not sure why the rest didn't work.

Comment: Perhaps you can share the error messages and your attempts to install n to the question so that we can help you with that?

Comment: I guess the install node command in laravel forge has to specific. Not entirely sure it could be because of permissions against the installation of some packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to fardjad for the help. I was to update node successfully using the specific command below. It seems that laravel forge doesn't accept other commands like npm install n to update node, only this specific one.

```
npm i node
```